# Python ctypes misbehaves when a C function returns a dynamic array

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm working on Python wrapper classes for Matlab's dynamic libraries to read Matlab MAT files in Python, and I'm encountering an odd behavior that I cannot explain from the ctypes interface.

The C function signature looks like this:

```c
    const mwSize *mxGetDimensions(const mxArray *);
```

Here, `mwSize` is a renamed `size_t`, and `mxArray*` is an opaque pointer. This function returns the "shape" of the Matlab array. The returned pointer points to the size_t array, which is stored internally within mxArray object and is **not** null terminated (its size is obtained via another function).

To call this function from Python, I set up the library as follows:

```py
    libmx = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libmx.dll')
    libmx.mxGetDimensions.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_size_t)
    libmx.mxGetDimensions.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
```

and after obtained `mxArray*` in `VAR`, I called:

```py
    dims = libmx.mxGetDimensions(VAR)
    print(dims[0],dims[1])
```

`VAR` is known to be 2-D and has a shape of `(1, 13)` (validated with a C program) but my Python code returns `(55834574849 0)` in c_ulonglong... Results are consistently garbage across all the variables stored in the test MAT file.

What am I doing wrong? Other library calls using VAR seems be working properly, so VAR is pointing to the valid object. As stated above, mxGetDimensions() called in a C program works as expected.

Any inputs would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Well, actually converting `55834574849` to hex gives the answer :) `55834574849` -> `0xD 0000 0001` so it seems that it's an array of `uint32_t`. Try with a `restype` set to `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint32)` and tell us if it works.

Comment: @Neitsa - Beautiful. That was it. It is curious how the discrepancy came about in Python & C calls, though. In my C test code, I verified that size_t is indeed uint64_t... Anyways, thank you! (If you could repost it as an answer, I'll accept it for your credit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Neitsa solved my immediate issue in his comment under the OP, and further investigation of libmx.dll resolved the remaining discrepancy between Python & C versions.

Because Matlab's libmx.dll goes back really long time as it was first written in the 32-bit era, the DLL contains multiple versions of its functions for backward compatibility. As it turned out, `const mwSize *mxGetDimensions(const mxArray *);` is the oldest version of the function, and the associated C header file (matrix.h) has the line `#define mxGetDimensions mxGetDimensions_800` to override the function with its newest version. Obviously, Python's ctypes doesn't check the C header file; so, it was left for me to sift through the header file figuring out which version of the function to use.

In the end, the proper behavior with `POINTER(c_size_t)` was obtained when I changed my code to:

```py
    libmx = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libmx.dll')
    libmx.mxGetDimensions_800.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_size_t)
    libmx.mxGetDimensions_800.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]

    dims = libmx.mxGetDimensions_800(VAR)
```

So, there you have it: Study the associated header file thoroughly if you are wrapping a 3rd-party dynamic/shared library.